# How to get around nesting limit on Power Automate?

Tags: microsoft-power-automate-desktop

I'm trying to use Power Automate to automate some of our Returns process.

A customer submits a return via Microsoft Forms, where they include their details and what products they're sending back. Each product is a separate answer, to allow me to use the input to populate a Returns Document which they receive by email and include in their return.

I'm using conditions to gather how many products are being returned "Is there a 2nd, is there a 3rd, is there a 4th" etc. However, this quickly reaches the nesting limit. Especially as my next set of questions is, if they opt for an exchange, what products are you exchanging for.

Does anybody know a way around this? Am i able to trigger the next action, rather than continue in a nest?

If i cannot get this to work i'll either have to go almost completely manual, or start from scratch and re-think my approach. So i will greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can only get around the nesting limit of Power Automate by changing
your code.

Here are two ideas :

- Switch case Control
  This has no limits, but it only accepts strings and integers when
  comparing values.
- Multiple conditions within the same Condition Control
  If you have multiple conditions with the same outcome, you can add
  multiple rows of conditions.

Reference :
[3 ways to build multiple conditions in Microsoft Flow](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-to-build-multiple-conditions-in-microsoft-flow/)